# How to display a portion of a string at an index of a string array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a string array

```
String[] albumnames;
```

now how to take a string from particular index position with limited number of charachters.

For example,
 if, albumnames[position] have value "abcdefghijk"
 then i want to take the first 5 characters only.
That is "abcde".

Comment: Added String newString = albumnames[position].substring(0, 5);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `substring` method of String can be used to achieve this. Try

```
String s = albumnames[position].substring(0,5);
```

See [substring docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)

Comment: When posting such an answer, at least post link to the method from the docs.

Answer (score 0):

albumnames[position].substring(0,5);

Answer (score 0):

you can see the methods in String class, like substring, indexof